# object.style.fontSize not retrieving value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently moved the CSS styling on a div tag from inline styling to an external stylesheet. The CSS for the tag is as follows:

```
#ntext{
position:absolute; 
top:204px; 
left:100px; 
width:197px; 
height:45px; 
text-align:center; 
font-size:24px; 
white-space:nowrap; 
color:#FFFFFF; 
font-family:Times New Roman, Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif}
```

I  have a JavaScript function that is meant to reduce the font size of this div that is as follows:

```
function rdText()
{var tXt = document.getElementById("ntext");
var fstring = tXt.style.fontSize;
var fnum = parseInt(fstring);
fnum -=1 ;
tXt.style.fontSize= fnum+"px"}
```

This function worked before I moved the styling but now it does not. I tracked the problem down to .style.fontSize not receiving the value of the font size attribute as it didn't return the correct value ("24px") when tested with alert(). The CSS appears to be attached properly because functions that change other parts like color work just fine. I was also able to adjust the font size manually in the style sheet.

I'm probably making a really stupid mistake here but for the life of me I don't know what it is.

Comment: What do you see if do `console.log(tXt.style)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a job for getComputedStyle()

```
function rdText(){
  var tXt = document.getElementById("ntext");
  var fnum = parseInt(getComputedStyle(tXt)['font-size']);
  fnum -=1 ;
  tXt.style.fontSize= fnum+"px"
}
```

if you need to support old IE: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

Comment: Don't forget the radix for parseInt.

Comment: @stavarotti: dom props never pad zeros, so a formal radix is not needed in this case. some folks over-code for one reason or the other, but i don't.

Comment: Thank you so much! Should I also be using getComputedStyle() for changing other things about the CSS like color and font, althoug they seem to work with object.style  ?

Comment: @Ducky: if something is reachable as .style.something, use that instead of incurring the extra overhead of getComputedStyle(), which as you might have noticed, actually calculates every single .style property, making it a lot slower than a single property lookup.

Comment: @dandavis Fair enough.  I have always done so for [clarity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters)

Comment: @stavarotti: as an aside, the octal default is changing to decimal default, if your particular browser hasn't already done so...